# string spacing in json, that will be displayed in HTML page by JS script code

Tags: html, json

Hi I have a webpage that contains multi-languages

I created a JSON file that has a key for each word on the page

but I want to but an empty language ( don't ask me why ) that's like this:

**the original word `Hi there` ==>**

so I created a thing like this in JSON

```
"langCode": "&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "langName": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",

    "services": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "clients": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "features": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "about": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "contact": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "letsBuildTheWwweb": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "teamOfDevelopersUiuxDesignersAndLogoDesigners": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "hireUs": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",

    "webDeveloping": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "cryptoSystem": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "logoDesinging": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "seoOptimazation": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "webHosting": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "adsOptimazation": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "webDesigning": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "uiUxDesinging": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "ecommerce": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    "domainRegistration": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
```

I insert json into HTML this way :

```
$.getJSON(dir, (lang) => {
    document.querySelector('.langCode').innerText = lang.langCode;
    });
```

when I open the page I see `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` everywhere not

**Dear moderators, I'm noob in StackOverflow so if I have wrongs in my questions don't delete it cuz I got banned 4 times**

Comment: How are you inserting this json data in HTML? More details required.

Comment: Read my comment again.

Comment: my reply still the same :)

Comment: Try `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`

Comment: @Omkar76 you can see in the question

Comment: @Alon Eitan answer this I'll accept it, it worked

Comment: @AlonEitan that's the issue. I didn't see your comment. I've deleted mine

Comment: @SagarV Please un-delete it :) So the OP can accept your answer

Comment: @Eymen Then read my comment **again**. I don't know what's so hard to understand about it. If you get banned here, it's not because the mods "hate you", it's because you managed to misbehave in such a way that the mods used the last resort they have available. And if you don't stop and think *right now*, it will happen again.

Comment: @Eymen Welcome to [SO]. If you're talking about question ban, they're automatic and not imposed by mods. If you're having a hard time figuring out why this happens, feel free to visit the [ask] section and [mcve]. When your questions get lot of negative scores/ got deleted, that will trigger the ban. The resources will help you to craft your question in a good way :-)

Comment: No, I'm not a moderator. Those have badges next to their usernames. I'm just good at predicting the future sometimes. If you get banned on this site, you *will* be told a reason for the ban. Nobody gets banned and never told why.

Answer (score 2):

Change each `&nbsp;` your JSON to `\u00a0`:

```
{
  "langCode": "\u00a0\u00a0",
  "langName": "\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0",
  "services": "\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0",
  "clients": "\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0",
  "features": "\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0"
}
```

`&nbsp;` is the HTML escape sequence for the non-breaking space. JSON is not HTML, the proper escape sequence in JSON is `\u00a0` ([Unicode Character 'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)).

Comment: in JSON file a bug says _Invalid escape character in string.json(261)_

Comment: @Eymen My bad, I meant `\u00a0`.

Comment: The problem is use of innerText instead of innerHTML

Comment: @SagarV No, that's not the problem. That's a possible solution to the problem, and a bad one at that, because for one thing, the OP very likely uses some framework to bring in the translations, and changing that might be difficult. And for another thing, switching to `.innerHTML` opens the door for XSS attacks or rendering bugs and therefore causes more harm than good. The problem is that the OP wants non-breaking spaces in their JSON, and `&nbsp;` is not the way to do that.

Comment: @SagarV it both worked,
thank you all guys